# Error creating firestore database: Resource in projects "gcp id" is the subject of a conflict: Database already exists. Please use another database_id

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, gcloud

I am trying to create googl cloud firestore database using the following command:

gcloud alpha firestore databases create --location=northamerica-northeast1 --type=firestore-native

This was working fine few days back. After a recent gcloud update the command has started failing with the error:

ERROR: (gcloud.alpha.firestore.databases.create) Resource in projects "google cloud project id" is the subject of a conflict: Database already exists. Please use another database_id

PS: I do create glcoud app before running the above command using the following:
gcloud app create --region=northamerica-northeast1

I tried adding using the command without alpha but still the same error.

Also tried setting the database id using --database flag

gcloud alpha firestore databases create --location=northamerica-northeast1 --type=firestore-native --database=default

Comment: You can only have one Firestore database per project. Have you already created a Firestore database in that project?

Comment: @anothermh No. Did not create a firestore database. The command is run for newly created gcp project. Also the gcp project is created using the gcloud commands only.

Comment: What is the output of `gcloud firestore databases list`?

Answer (score 1):

Try creating with new Project ID -

```bash
gcloud firestore databases create --location=${REGION} --database=newname
```

Feel free to use your custom name instead of "newname".